how to remove a specific column from csv string
I have a csv string from which i need to remove a specific column as while parsing its not able to understand double quotes and concatenates two records as one array
var a = 'Employee ID,UID,Name,Manager,Manager Name,Hire Date,Terminated,International Assignee,Paymix,Working Days,Annualization Month,Base Pay,Salary Prorated(Days),Currency,Country,Area,Quarter,KPI Name,Weight %,KPI Code,Target__c,Actual__c,Performance %,Payout %,KPI Incentive Bonus,OTE Flag,Reason, OTE Start Date, OTE End Date,Comments,Test Id,ID,Test Plan\n' +
'13333333,jjjuuuujj,iikkk,1111111,Jose test,2017-08-21,,0,80%,60,12,11111,111111.032786885245286612189374864101409912109375,EUR,"Spain","South West Europe Area",Q1,"test",40%,30-All-11111,199,201.00,103.10%,100.00%,989.80,false,Transfer to a new sales role,2024-03-01,2024-03-31,"tesr was appointe, so he needd to be measured as with the current Targets fm 01/01/2024 until 29/02/2024, proportionally to 2/3 of the Quarter. Then fm 01/03/2024 upto 31/03/2024.",1111111,2222222,"",'

var countrec = 0
var newCsv = a.split('\n').map(function (line) {
     var columns = line.split(',');
            columns.splice(1,30); // I want to remove "Comments" column from csvstring 
            return columns;
        }).join('\n');

console.log(newCsv);

papa parse approach
   const parseStream = Papa.parse(a, {
        header: false, quoteChar: '"', delimiter: ",", skipEmptyLines: true, trim: true, skipFirstNLines: 0,
        step: function (row) {
            if (!Object.values(row.data).every(value => value === '0')) {
                csvData.push(row.data)
            }
        },
        complete: function (results, file) {
            console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file);
        },
        transform: function (value) {
            return (!value) ? '0' : value;
        },
    })


The issue clearly appears to stem from the fact, that you chose the most "naive" approach to parsing CSV data possible - by simply splitting at commas. You tagged this with papaparse - so why aren't you actually using that parser library?

i have postted the papaparse approach which i tried, but i am not sure how to skip the column . i am not getting anything in the document

If you parse it properly, then why would you still need to "skip" a column?

i have a comment on one of the record like this .. [, , , , "due to how late she started in Dec""., 1111, 1111, ].  Whats happening is after parsing i am seeing the string is looking like this ["due to how late she started in Dec., 1111, 1111"]. Due to this reason i wanted to remove the column. Due to this issue i am unable to insert it in database

So this is a case of already "defective" input data. If at all possible, let it get fixed at that end then. Because your wish to remove "a column", when you can't parse this into the correct columns to begin with, is of course a bit of a catch-22 situation.

ok will try .. but still if there is any possibility to remove the column then please help

Simply splitting at comma is pretty much out of the question, if you can have commas in the values. And specifying enclosure & escape characters when parsing is not going to help, if those are not used properly and consistently across all records. At most I could perhaps see an attempt to fix this particular mishap by using a regular expression on the content before you try to parse it - but that is probably still going to be rather error prone.

So, the old rule applies once again "Garbage in => Garbage out". Your input file is invalid. The proper way to go is, fix the problem at the generating site where this CSV is created. Everything else is error prone and may (or may not) work. And because of that erroneous file structure it's quite impossible to give advice, because we don't know what kind of errors can occur in your file ...

Is that public info in that test data?  Seems private.  Hopefully it’s fake.


remove the trailing comma from the data or add another header field.
Use the step with the correct processing and an intermediate variable

This script will remove by name and also remove entries with value:0
I did not read the documentation in depth. There may be a built-in way to do this, but so far I see the issue has not been solved in the github repo


const unwantedFields = ["Terminated", "International Assignee", "Test Plan"]; // Fields you want to remove by name

const cleanData = (data) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).filter(
      ([key, value]) => value !== "0" && !unwantedFields.includes(key)
    )
  );
let cleanedData = [];
const parseStream = Papa.parse(inputData, {
  header: true,
  quoteChar: '"',
  delimiter: ",",
  skipEmptyLines: true,
  trim: true,
  skipFirstNLines: 0,
  step: (row) => {
    const cleanedRow = cleanData(row.data);
    cleanedData.push(cleanedRow);
  },
  complete: (results, file) => {
    results.data = cleanedData; // Assign the cleaned data to results.data
    console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file);
  },
});


console.log(parseStream)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.4.1/papaparse.min.js" integrity="sha512-dfX5uYVXzyU8+KHqj8bjo7UkOdg18PaOtpa48djpNbZHwExddghZ+ZmzWT06R5v6NSk3ZUfsH6FNEDepLx9hPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
const inputData = `Employee ID,UID,Name,Manager,Manager Name,Hire Date,Terminated,International Assignee,Paymix,Working Days,Annualization Month,Base Pay,Salary Prorated(Days),Currency,Country,Area,Quarter,KPI Name,Weight %,KPI Code,Target__c,Actual__c,Performance %,Payout %,KPI Incentive Bonus,OTE Flag,Reason, OTE Start Date, OTE End Date,Comments,Test Id,ID,Test Plan
13333333,FHG009,itorino,1111111,Jose test,2017-08-21,,0,80%,60,12,11111,111111.032786885245286612189374864101409912109375,EUR,"Spain","South West Europe Area",Q1,"Ocean Volume",40%,30-All-11111,199,201.00,103.10%,100.00%,989.80,false,Transfer to a new sales role,2024-03-01,2024-03-31,"Fabio was appointed as new Head of Reefer, so he needed to be measured as Sales Owner with the current Targets fm 01/01/2024 until 29/02/2024, proportionally to 2/3 of the Quarter. Then should be OTE fm 01/03/2024 upto 31/03/2024.",1111111,2222222,""`
</script>




As this is correct in principle, it won't be able to solve OP's problem, because according to the comments, OP has defective input data, which also Papa won't be able to parse correctly.

The data works if he removes the very last comma

It certainly does not in the case OP mentioned in the comments (which is not part of the data in the question), ie a string that contains a doublequote which is not correctly escaped

Ah, that is not good, but perhaps it IS escaped in the raw data
